# The distribution of the product of two random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, uniform-distribution

$X\sim \mathcal{Normal}(0,1)$ random variable.
$Y\sim \mathcal{Uniform}(\{-1,1\})$ random variable, independent of $X.$
Show that $Z=XY$ is a normal random variable.

I tried to solve it through double integral but it failed to do. There should be a trick to solve this.

Comment: The conclusion is false.  Did you perhaps mean to stipulate that $Y$ is a random variable that takes the values $\{-1,1\}$ with equal probability (of $1/2$ each)?  Regardless, please consult our [help] about asking questions and kindly tell us what attempts you have made at this question and where specifically you could use some help.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean by U(1,-1).Sorry for inconvenience but isn't it U(-1,1) general notation for that?

Comment: @arke No, it is $U\{-1, +1\}$

Comment: arke, "$U(-1,1)$" without further adornment is generally taken to be a continuous uniform distribution between $-1$ and $1$ ... for which the statement is untrue. If you want a 50-50 chance of the values -1 and 1, you'd specify it differently.

Comment: Thanks all helping me correct my notation.However, do have any idea why the conclusion is wrong if it is U(-1,1)(I know now it is uniform but I just wonder there is any proof also for that."

Comment: For the continuous uniform, you'd have a mixture of normal distributions at different scales; such a scale-mixture of normals is much more heavily peaked than a normal.

Comment: If you are still interested you should edit the Q to include all the informatin in comments!

Answer (score 2):

Since $Y$ takes on the values $\pm 1$ with equal probability, the product is $X$ with 50% probability and $-X$ with 50% probability. Since both (by the symmetry of the standard normal distribution) are standard normal random variables,  You can now complete the answer yourself.